# regex backtracking options: shrinking or expanding?

Tags: regex, backtracking

So far in my studies of regex I've come to a conclusion that whenever backtracking occurs, token that is currently "in the backtracking spot" will either try to expand (provided that it was followed by a lazy quantifier; say, x*? that initially grabbed "x" will try to grab another x to become "xx") or to shrink (only provided it was followed by a greedy quantifier; x*, which originally grabbed "xxx" will try to release one x to hold "xx"). It is my understanding that these actions are strictly determined by the type of the quantifier that follows the token.

But this somehow contradicts to the info provided in this section of regex tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html.
There author gives an exapmle of string being searched -

```
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13" and regex - "^([^,\r\n]*,){11}P".
```

Further he notes: "if the P cannot be found, the engine will still backtrack. But it will backtrack only 11 times, and each time the `[^,\r\n]` is not able to **expand** beyond the comma, forcing the regex engine to the previous one of the 11 iterations immediately, without trying further options".

This word "expand" is the one that confuses me a lot. Will the token ever try to expand at this point when it backtracks? Should the regex have been written something like this: `"^([^,\r\n]*?,){11}P",` no question would ever arise, but now I am wondering whether I got the concept of backtracking right
or not.?

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Comment: At this level of specificity and detail, it might be best to first decide upon a particular regex engine and then attempt to discover its behavior.

Comment: I'm looking at regex behavior in Java, but does it really matter in this case?

Answer (score 1):

All he's saying is that `[^,\r\n]*` will never consume characters beyond a comma, which is the separator.

If the character set did not include the comma, then the amount of backtracking would increase catastrophically, because it's a subpattern which is repeated.

Comment: He is actually saying that _while_ backtracking in this particular case, regex engine won't be able to expand. But here regex would expand only when matching in the first time, and shrink when backtracking. This might look like word-splitting, but is actually quite important for me to grasp this concept.